# Can I: loop through sql select and then fire off for each loop?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm probably missing something (looking at it too long), but in a stored procedure can I select all distinct values from one table and then do a for each loop based on each of those returned rows, which themselves build up sql statements based on the distinct values?

Cheers.

Comment: Quick answer = yes, use cursours as LukeH mentions. If I'm reading this right...you're attempting to build dynamic sql in loops. Quite ambitious if you're newer to SQL, but there are some things can can only be accomplished like this. Anytime you are looking at a loop in SQL, you should ask yourself if that loop is needed and attempt a set-based solution instead. It is possible you've found an occasion where dynamic sql built in cursor loops is the only solution...but my guess is we can accomplish what you want without a loop. Want to share more info on what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can [use a cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181441.aspx).

Note that cursors are best avoided if possible. If it's possible to do what you need with a set-based query -- and it often is -- then you should do that instead.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Nevertheless, this kind of requirement usually points to some more general problem in your (@mailman1979) architecture or code.

Comment: Hi, Cheers for your answers. In the end I managed to use a set based query.